# My Facebook app not appears in facebook search result

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-apps

I've created a new facebook application at developer.facebook.com with following details:

Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/158158040982233

My application has 200MAU.

However, this app is not appearing in search results, if i am trying to search in under search textbox at facebook, what can be the reason?

Please guide me,

Thanks, Baris.

Answer (score 2):

Wait for some time , even i have faced same problem. I think it will take some time to reflect.

And make sure that your "sandbox mode" should be disabled.

Comment: You need to have been over 10 MAU for 2-4 weeks before the app is added to the index

Answer (score 0):

It could be missing for a number of reasons, for example, is the `Social Discovery` option for your app enabled? Does it have a App Fan Page? Is Sandbox Mode enabled?

Having a App Fan Page will increase the changes of you App appearing in Search. Using FBML will also cause your app to not appear in search results. Sandbox mode will mean user's won't see you app in search results either.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are now automatically indexed when they reach 10 MAU. It is no longer necessary to manually "Submit to Search" as per blog on Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/07/12/getting-your-apps-into-facebook-search-faster/